# Query json data on MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a rather complex structure on my json and I cannot find how to query it to get the rows I am interested in. Here is a sample of my data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5282bf9ce4b05216ca1b68f8"),
    "authorID" : ObjectId("5282a8c3e4b0d7f4f4d07b9a"),
    "blogID" : "7180831558698033600",
    "blogs" : {
        "$" : {
            "posts" : [
                [
                    {
                        "author" : {
                            "displayName" : "mms",
                            ...
                            ...
                            ...
}}}
```

So, I am interested in finding all json entries that have the author displayName equal to "mms".

My collection name is bz so, a find all query would be: db.dz.find()

What criteria do I have to put inside the find() to only get json document with author displayName equal to mms?

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `"$"` is not a recommended field name.

Comment: Not just not recommended, it's not allowed or supported. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Thanks for your information. Now I see that V2.6 rejects it even on `update` operation. By the way, the manual's description is not precise enough. `$` is allowed in field name but not as the first character.

Comment: Well, this query works for me:
db.dz.find({"blogs.$.cat" : "red"})

So, in this case $ works a field name.

Comment: Your problem will be, that `$` is a "placeholder" character in a Mongo query. It means, "this item you've found matching the criteria". This will make your queries confusing when you eventually need one that uses the `$` operator/helper. It will not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have replaced field name "$" with "dollarSign".

Then `db.dz.find({"blogs.dollarSign.posts.author.displayName": "mms"})` will fetch whole documents according to your requirements.

Comment: I tried this. It does not throw an exception but it does not bring back any result either. I have not replaces the $ field because as I write in my previous comment this does not cause any problems in my case.